# Evernote update does not work

Tags: updates, evernote

Automatic Evernote update says there is new version. I click "Download and install", download probably works as the progressbar slowly fills up. Then Evernote restarts but version is still the same and new update window pops up telling me there is new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, minute after I asked this question I realized answer is quite simple:

1. Go to Evernote options Tools/Options
2. Click Open Database Folder and go one level up and go to Updates. You should be in `C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Local Settings\Application Data\Evernote\Evernote\Updates`
3. Quit Evernote by clicking exit in system tray icon context menu
4. Run Evernote updater from the folder you navigated to earlier. It is `Evernote_updater_3.5.1.1410.exe` in my case.
5. Follow on-screen install instructions and Evernote should be installed

Comment: I will, but I can do it after two days.